# Optimal creation new empty element in std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, std-pair

For inserting new elements `std::map` requires presence `std::pair` object. 
I didn't find an alternative method to add a new element into `std::map` without constructing such `std::pair` object.

But suppose the `std::map` value is a heavy object consuming a lot of resources. Inserting such element into `std::map` constraints one unnecessary copy. In the case 
I have some object X needed to be copied directly into `std::map`, std authors constrain me to perform this copy in two steps:

1. copy X->`std::pair`
2. copy pair obj -> `std::map` insert location.

How to eliminate these unneeded copy? Implementing Move constructor doesn't solve my problem - the copy still exists.

I suspect some method in `std::map` which inserts a new empty element with some key but no value, without calling any constructor for the value. Then I can move the value to thereby my own way.
But I don't find such method in `std::map`!

Comment: `Implementing Move constructor doesn't solve my problem - the copy still exists.` Why?

Comment: Default move constructor do the same as the usual copy constructor. Implementing my own Move constructor cause other overhead. I am looking for simple technique not using std::pair when adding.

Comment: Giving class users access to a potential object's storage without an actual object there would be a more complicated implementation that mostly just provides a way to make dangerous mistakes. If you really need the map to sometimes have keys with no values, you might consider using a `std::map<Key, std::optional<Value>>`.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [std::map::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the `std::map` *value* is a heavy object consuming a lot of resources. Inserting such element into `std::map` constraints one unnecessary
>   copy. How to eliminate these unneeded copy?

You are right about this and [**`std::map::emplace`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) is the only solution what we have available now. A small explanation about the use of `std::map::emplace` from  [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)  is given below:

> Careful use of `emplace` allows the new element to be constructed while
>   avoiding *unnecessary copy or move operations*. The constructor of the
>   new element (i.e. `std::pair<const Key, T>`) is called with **exactly the**
>   **same arguments as supplied to emplace**, forwarded via
>   `std::forward<Args>(args)....`

That means the a class-instances can be constructed **in-place at the time of map insert**(i.e, *instead of constructing and copying*), via `std::map::emplace`, when you provide a contractor in the class with exactly same arguments. And then, you need to use `std::map::emplace` along with **[`std::piecewise_construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct)** and **[`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)**(assuming that the class contains more than one member).

```
myMap.emplace(
        std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(/*key of map*/),
        std::forward_as_tuple(/*all the members which you want to constrct in place*/)
    );
```

To demonstrate the above case, I have made a small sample code in which the members of `ClassA` will be constructed in place without calling any of the special member functions. To make it sure, I have disabled `default`, `copy` and `move` constructors.

<kbd>**[SEE LIVE HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Cce2MUHTWWNLtyw7)**</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

class ClassA
{
    int _val;
    std::string _str;
public:
    explicit ClassA(const int val, const std::string& str) : _val(val), _str(str)
    {
        std::cout << "A class: C'tor called...!\n";
    }
    // disable the following
    ClassA() = delete;
    ClassA(const ClassA&) = delete;
    ClassA& operator=(const ClassA&) = delete;
    ClassA(ClassA&&) = delete;
    ClassA& operator=(ClassA&&) = delete;

};

class ClassB
{
    ClassA _aObj;
public:
    explicit ClassB(const int val, const std::string& str) : _aObj(val, str)
    {
        std::cout << "B class: C'tor called...!\n";
    }
    // disable the following
    ClassB() = delete;
    ClassB(const ClassB&) = delete;
    ClassB& operator=(const ClassB&) = delete;
    ClassB(ClassB&&) = delete;
    ClassB& operator=(ClassB&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, ClassB> myMap;
    myMap.emplace(
        std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(1),
        std::forward_as_tuple(1, "some string")
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A class: C'tor called...!
B class: C'tor called...!
```

---

**Update**: On the other hand,

> The element may be constructed **even if**
>   there **already is an element with the key** in the container, in which
>   case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately.

That means, your expectation(or assumption) of:

**"** *I suspect some method in `std::map` which inserts a new empty element with **some key** but **no value**, without calling any constructor for the value. Then I can move the value to thereby my own way.* **"**

is **not possible** to achieve, by above mentioned `std::map::emplace` way. As @aschepler pointed out in the comments, you can have maps with sometimes(optional) keys and no values by using the C++17 feature **[`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)**.

For that, you need to make the values as optional as follows and of course the compiler version support C++17 or later.

```
std::map<Key, std::optional<Value>> myMap;
```

Now you can construct an object anytime in the code and after a while, you can move it to appropriate key-value(i.e, entry). Last but not least, don't forget to provide [*default move-c'ntors*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

<kbd>**[SEE SAMPLE CODE HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FM19JZf45xRMXxH6)**</kbd>

```
#include <optional>

class ClassA {
    /* same as before*/
public:
    // disable the copy c'tor
    // enable move c'ntors
    ClassA(ClassA&&) = default;
    ClassA& operator=(ClassA&&) = default;

};

class ClassB {
    /* same as before*/
public:
    // disable the copy c'tor
    // enable move c'ntors
    ClassB(ClassB&&) = default;
    ClassB& operator=(ClassB&&) = default;
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::optional<ClassB>> myMap;
    // created without calling any constructors
    myMap.emplace(1, std::nullopt);
    //later in the code
    ClassB bObj{1, "JeJo"};
    // again after..... move it to the required key-value
    myMap[1] = std::move(bObj);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A class: C'tor called...!
B class: C'tor called...!
```

Comment: After investigating your example and performing my own tests, I see the key thing causing `map::emplace` to work as you explained, is using `std::piecewise_construct` as the 1st parameter. Without this trick `map::emplace` causes 2 constructors calls. Moreover, the usual `map::insert` results 3 (!) constructor calls when inserting! I think such not intuitive behaviour may be improved in the standard.

Comment: @RedSoft Yes. I have experienced this a while ago and then after made a research I found out this. One more thing to note that, if your class has only a single element in it, you don't need the mimic explained above. :) I think I have mentioned about it in my previous edit.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `std::map::emplace`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

Comment: `emplace` doesn't eliminate calling `std::pair` constructor, and, as result, the constructor of my value